# Mobile drop-down menu toggle "working" but never visible

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a pretty basic mobile drop-down menu that expands on click for the top-right nav of [this codepen portfolio page project for Free Code Camp.](http://codepen.io/prospect_ii/pen/XdbVmB) The menu never shows up, but when I inspect the element it seems like the javascript function is actually working, with the "show" CSS class being added and removed to the mobileNavDrop div.

The invisible menu also seems to be located on the page where it's supposed to be, as can be seen in this screenshot using the inspect element tool:

[Invisible drop-down menu highlighted with inspect element tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdq0j.png)

I've tried pushing it all the way forward with z-index and making the banner invisible to see if it's hiding behind things, but it isn't. I even tried just having the menu start as visible rather than with "display: none;" and it still doesn't show up on the page.

The advice I've gotten elsewhere is to just use jquery and bootstrap, but I'd hoped to understand things more by trying to just write everything from scratch. So it's possible something I wrote for the responsive layout is conflicting?

Here's at least the sections of code that I thought would be relevant. Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<div class='container-navbar'>
    <div class='navbar'>

        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-sm-2 col-md-1'>
                <ul class='nav-left'>
                    <li class='header-button'><a href='http://www.freecodecamp.com/davallerr' target='_blank'>davallerr</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class='col-sm-2 col-md-3'>
                <div class='mobile-nav'>
                    <i onclick='mobileNavDrop()' class='fa fa-bars mobile-nav-icon'></i>
                    <div id='mobileNavDrop' class='mobile-nav-drop'>
                        <a href='#about'>about</a>
                        <a href='#portfolio'>the work</a>
                        <a href='#contact'>contact</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul class='nav-right'>
                    <li><a href='#about'>about</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#portfolio'>the work</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#contact'>contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mobile-nav-icon {
    padding: 1.25em;
}

.mobile-nav-icon:hover, .mobile-nav-icon:focus {
    background: #40514f;
    color: #fff;
}

.mobile-nav {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    overflow: visible;
}

.mobile-nav-drop {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background: #ccc;
    min-width: 10em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 .25em 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.show {
    display: block;
}

.mobile-nav-drop a {
    color: #000;
    padding: 1em;
    display: block;
}

.mobile-nav-drop a:hover {
    background: #aaa;
}
```

**JS**

```
function mobileNavDrop() {
    document.getElementById('mobileNavDrop').classList.toggle('show');
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.mobile-nav-icon')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('mobile-nav-drop');
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

```
.show {
    display: block;
    position: absolute; /* add this line, */
    top: 0; /* and this one */
}
```

Plus, make sure the overflow is visible in every container of that `nav` that might not be large enough to contain the drop-down menu.

Comment: Thanks so much, it was the overflow visibility of its parent row and container that was doing it. They both have it hidden by default and needed to be overridden for that case.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not seeing the icon because you have not included the [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/) library for the icon (`fa fa-bars`).

try adding this cdn reference to your `<head>`:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

or download and install a local copy.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function mobileNavDrop() {
    document.getElementById('mobileNavDrop').classList.toggle('show');
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.mobile-nav-icon')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('mobile-nav-drop');
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }else
            {
                openDropdown.classList.contains('show');
            }
        }
    }
};
```

```css
.mobile-nav-icon {
    padding: 1.25em;
}
.mobile-nav-icon{
background-color:grey;
}

.mobile-nav-icon:hover, .mobile-nav-icon:focus {
    background: #40514f;
    color: darkgrey;
}

.mobile-nav {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    overflow: visible;
}

.mobile-nav-drop {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background: #ccc;
    min-width: 10em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 .25em 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.hide{
    display: none;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}

.mobile-nav-drop a {
    color: #000;
    padding: 1em;
    display: block;
}

.mobile-nav-drop a:hover {
    background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='container-navbar'>
    <div class='navbar'>

        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-sm-4 col-md-1'>
                <ul class='nav-left'>
                    <li class='header-button'><a href='http://www.freecodecamp.com/davallerr' target='_blank'>davallerr</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class='col-sm-4 col-md-3'>
                <div class='mobile-nav'>
                    <div onclick='mobileNavDrop()' class='fa fa-bars mobile-nav-icon'></div>
                    <div id='mobileNavDrop' class='mobile-nav-drop hide'>
                        <a href='#about'>about</a>
                        <a href='#portfolio'>the work</a>
                        <a href='#contact'>contact</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul class='nav-right'>
                    <li><a href='#about'>about</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#portfolio'>the work</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#contact'>contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

In your javascript. I added an else statement so it toggles back and forth.
Your statement only removes 'show' but does not add it back.

Comment: I hope this is a part of what you are asking for and not just because the icon is missing. To point it out, I changed the icon to a div and made it darkgrey to see it. There are 2 things going on. 1. icon is not visible - see other answers for the solution. 2. class 'show' removed but not put back. This will only mean the element remains display:none;